# why my tooltip or tootip value go to display none when i hover on range slider thumb?

Tags: javascript, html, css, range, tooltip

So when I hover over my range slider thumb, the tooltip displays none, but when I refresh or hold the range slider slider thumb, it displays perfectly.

I want my range slider tooltip to always be in display mode, as opposed to disappearing when I only hover over those slider thumbs. It should always be the same and visible to the user. Also the tooltip is not centered top of the thumb. I didnt find the way to make the tooltip to be exact centered top of the thumb.

My code -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
    .middle {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.slider {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  height: var(--2, 8px);
}

.slider>.track {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #E5E7EB;
}

.slider>.range {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 25%;
  right: 25%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #1C64F2;
}

.slider>.thumb {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(98, 0, 238, .1);
  transition: box-shadow .3s ease-in-out;
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke: var(--gray-200, #E5E7EB);
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08));
}

.slider>.thumb.left {
  left: 25%;
  transform: translate(-15px, -10px);
}

.slider>.thumb.right {
  right: 25%;
  transform: translate(15px, -10px);
}

input[type=range] {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  pointer-events: all;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 0 none;
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background-color: #1C64F2;
  color: #FFFFFF;

  padding: var(--05, 2px) var(--2, 8px);
 
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  opacity: 1;
  top: -40px !important;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="price-range-section mt-5">
        <label for="Price Range">Price Range</label>
        <div class="middle">
          <div class="multi-range-slider">
            <input type="range" id="price-min-slider" min="0" max="100" value="25">
            <input type="range" id="price-max-slider" min="0" max="100" value="75">
      
            <div class="slider">
              <div class="track"></div>
              <div class="range"></div>
              <div class="thumb left"></div>
              <div class="thumb right"></div>
            </div>
      
            <!-- Tooltips -->
            <div class="tooltip" id="tooltip-left"></div>
            <div class="tooltip" id="tooltip-right"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    


      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        var PriceMinSlider = document.getElementById("price-min-slider");
var PriceMaxSlider = document.getElementById("price-max-slider");

var thumbLeft = document.querySelector(".slider > .thumb.left");
var thumbRight = document.querySelector(".slider > .thumb.right");
var range = document.querySelector(".slider > .range");

var tooltipLeft = document.getElementById("tooltip-left");
var tooltipRight = document.getElementById("tooltip-right");

function setLeftValue() {
  var _this = PriceMinSlider,
    min = parseInt(_this.min),
    max = parseInt(_this.max);

  _this.value = Math.min(parseInt(_this.value), parseInt(PriceMaxSlider.value) - 1);

  var percent = ((_this.value - min) / (max - min)) * 100;

  thumbLeft.style.left = percent + "%";
  range.style.left = percent + "%";
  updateTooltipPosition();
}

setLeftValue();

function setRightValue() {
  var _this = PriceMaxSlider,
    min = parseInt(_this.min),
    max = parseInt(_this.max);

  _this.value = Math.max(parseInt(_this.value), parseInt(PriceMinSlider.value) + 1);

  var percent = ((_this.value - min) / (max - min)) * 100;

  thumbRight.style.right = (100 - percent) + "%";
  range.style.right = (100 - percent) + "%";
  updateTooltipPosition();
}

setRightValue();

function updateTooltipPosition() {
  var thumbLeftPosition = thumbLeft.getBoundingClientRect();
  var thumbRightPosition = thumbRight.getBoundingClientRect();

  tooltipLeft.style.display = "block";
  tooltipLeft.style.left = thumbLeftPosition.left + "px";
  tooltipLeft.style.top = thumbLeftPosition.bottom + 5 + "px";
  tooltipLeft.innerHTML = PriceMinSlider.value;

  tooltipRight.style.display = "block";
  tooltipRight.style.left = thumbRightPosition.left + "px";
  tooltipRight.style.top = thumbRightPosition.bottom + 5 + "px";
  tooltipRight.innerHTML = PriceMaxSlider.value;
}

thumbLeft.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  tooltipLeft.style.display = "block";
});

thumbLeft.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
  tooltipLeft.style.display = "none";
});

thumbRight.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  tooltipRight.style.display = "block";
});

thumbRight.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
  tooltipRight.style.display = "none";
});

PriceMinSlider.addEventListener("input", setLeftValue);
PriceMaxSlider.addEventListener("input", setRightValue);

PriceMinSlider.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
  thumbLeft.classList.add("active");
});

PriceMinSlider.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
  thumbLeft.classList.remove("active");
});

PriceMaxSlider.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
  thumbRight.classList.add("active");
});

PriceMaxSlider.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
  thumbRight.classList.remove("active");
});



      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you trying to make the tooltip visible only when hovering on the thumb? If not what's the point making them `display:none` in the handlers?

Answer (score 1):

To make the tooltips on the range slider thumb always visible, you can just remove the mouseover and mouseout event listeners for the thumb elements.

Here is the updated code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <link
      href="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <style>
      .middle {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 500px;
      }

      .slider {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
        height: var(--2, 8px);
      }

      .slider > .track {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: #e5e7eb;
      }

      .slider > .range {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 2;
        left: 25%;
        right: 25%;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: #1c64f2;
      }

      .slider > .thumb {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 3;
        width: 22px;
        height: 22px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        border-radius: 50%;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(98, 0, 238, 0.1);
        transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out;
        stroke-width: 1px;
        stroke: var(--gray-200, #e5e7eb);
        filter: drop-shadow(0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08));
      }

      .slider > .thumb.left {
        left: 25%;
        transform: translate(-15px, -10px);
      }

      .slider > .thumb.right {
        right: 25%;
        transform: translate(15px, -10px);
      }

      input[type='range'] {
        position: absolute;
        pointer-events: none;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        z-index: 2;
        height: 10px;
        width: 100%;
        opacity: 0;
      }

      input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        pointer-events: all;
        width: 22px;
        height: 22px;
        border-radius: 0;
        border: 0 none;
        background-color: red;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
      }

      .tooltip {
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
        background-color: #1c64f2;
        color: #ffffff;

        padding: var(--05, 2px) var(--2, 8px);

        border-radius: 5px;
        font-size: 12px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        opacity: 1;
        top: -40px !important;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="price-range-section mt-5">
      <label for="Price Range">Price Range</label>
      <div class="middle">
        <div class="multi-range-slider">
          <input
            type="range"
            id="price-min-slider"
            min="0"
            max="100"
            value="25"
          />
          <input
            type="range"
            id="price-max-slider"
            min="0"
            max="100"
            value="75"
          />

          <div class="slider">
            <div class="track"></div>
            <div class="range"></div>
            <div class="thumb left"></div>
            <div class="thumb right"></div>
          </div>

          <!-- Tooltips -->
          <div class="tooltip" id="tooltip-left"></div>
          <div class="tooltip" id="tooltip-right"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var PriceMinSlider = document.getElementById('price-min-slider');
      var PriceMaxSlider = document.getElementById('price-max-slider');

      var thumbLeft = document.querySelector('.slider > .thumb.left');
      var thumbRight = document.querySelector('.slider > .thumb.right');
      var range = document.querySelector('.slider > .range');

      var tooltipLeft = document.getElementById('tooltip-left');
      var tooltipRight = document.getElementById('tooltip-right');

      function setLeftValue() {
        var _this = PriceMinSlider,
          min = parseInt(_this.min),
          max = parseInt(_this.max);

        _this.value = Math.min(
          parseInt(_this.value),
          parseInt(PriceMaxSlider.value) - 1
        );

        var percent = ((_this.value - min) / (max - min)) * 100;

        thumbLeft.style.left = percent + '%';
        range.style.left = percent + '%';
        updateTooltipPosition();
      }

      setLeftValue();

      function setRightValue() {
        var _this = PriceMaxSlider,
          min = parseInt(_this.min),
          max = parseInt(_this.max);

        _this.value = Math.max(
          parseInt(_this.value),
          parseInt(PriceMinSlider.value) + 1
        );

        var percent = ((_this.value - min) / (max - min)) * 100;

        thumbRight.style.right = 100 - percent + '%';
        range.style.right = 100 - percent + '%';
        updateTooltipPosition();
      }

      setRightValue();

      function updateTooltipPosition() {
        var thumbLeftPosition = thumbLeft.getBoundingClientRect();
        var thumbRightPosition = thumbRight.getBoundingClientRect();

        tooltipLeft.style.display = 'block';
        tooltipLeft.style.left = thumbLeftPosition.left + 'px';
        tooltipLeft.style.top = thumbLeftPosition.bottom + 5 + 'px';
        tooltipLeft.innerHTML = PriceMinSlider.value;

        tooltipRight.style.display = 'block';
        tooltipRight.style.left = thumbRightPosition.left + 'px';
        tooltipRight.style.top = thumbRightPosition.bottom + 5 + 'px';
        tooltipRight.innerHTML = PriceMaxSlider.value;
      }
      // ✅ Remove thumbLeft and thumbRight event listeners
      // thumbLeft.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
      //   tooltipLeft.style.display = 'block';
      // });

      // thumbLeft.addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
      //   tooltipLeft.style.display = 'none';
      // });

      // thumbRight.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
      //   tooltipRight.style.display = 'block';
      // });

      // thumbRight.addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
      //   tooltipRight.style.display = 'none';
      // });

      PriceMinSlider.addEventListener('input', setLeftValue);
      PriceMaxSlider.addEventListener('input', setRightValue);

      PriceMinSlider.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
        thumbLeft.classList.add('active');
      });

      PriceMinSlider.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
        thumbLeft.classList.remove('active');
      });

      PriceMaxSlider.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
        thumbRight.classList.add('active');
      });

      PriceMaxSlider.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
        thumbRight.classList.remove('active');
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```